# Ebay Finding Api: how to get searchResult.item.attribute?

Tags: ebay-api

The [docs](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html) mention it in the output section as an array of name/value pairs. Says they come "conditionally" but gives no clue about these conditions.
How can I get these fields?

Answer (score 1):

Best solution so far was [GetMultipleItems](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetMultipleItems.html#Samples) from Shopping API. It returns "attributes" for 20 items. You need to add "IncludeSelector=ItemSpecifics" and the list of item ids in the request.